# Choose different SCSS file according to a variable Angular 6 Typescript

Tags: angular, sass

I have an angular application. This application supports multiple languages with rtl and ltr layout. The layout will be changed according to the change of the languages from the user.

I have two SCSS files one for each direction.
I want to load one of them according to the value of a variable. I am lost and I don't know where should I exactly do it. What is the best practice for this kind of issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a class flag like `rtl` , `ltr` and import the selected theme (scss file) in the body of the class that mean when the class present the specific theme will apply.

*_ltr.scss*

```
h1 {
  background: #4285f4;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: left;
}
```

*_rtl.scss*

```
h1 {
  background: #ea4335;
  color:#fff;
  text-align: right;
}
```

*style.scss*

```
.rtl {
 @import "theme/_rtl.scss"
}

.ltr {
 @import "theme/_ltr.scss"
}
```

*compiled style.scss*

```
.rtl h1 {
    background: #ea4335;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right
}

.ltr h1 {
    background: #4285f4;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: left
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div>Selected theme :
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedTheme"> 
    <option value="rtl">RTL</option>
    <option value="ltr">LTR</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div [class]="selectedTheme">
    ....
</div>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-theme-class-flag)

Comment: Great idea actually. I think it could work. It is like a bit of a workaround, but a redux value could be set onetime and used all over the application.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (or, well, it doesn't make sense to) load different `.scss` files at runtime, since they firstly need to be compiled to CSS in order to work in the browser.

The other answer shows a way to do it by [bundling both versions of styles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51921231/2131286) for the two layouts, but depending on your code organization this could lead to a lot of duplicates which might not be ideal.

Other options include:

- use inline styles for the differences and change them via the binding syntax; eg. `[style.text-align]="direction"`;
- use [custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to determine the text dierction; you might also need to use [conditional statements in CSS](http://kizu.ru/en/fun/conditions-for-css-variables/) based on the nature of your styles
- if you are using build-time i18n (if you're building a separate application per language, where the user has to re-download the app in order to change the langauge), just use different CSS files for those apps

Comment: import at sass is different from css import ,the is no load different sass file the output file contain the both theme (rtl.ltr) and will be bundle as one file , you may check my answer

Comment: Himm, I think, I should load both of them. But I can use only the one I need. But I will take that in consideration.

Comment: @MuhammedAlbarmawi I am exactly talking about avoiding loading both styles: users who only even use LTR will need to download the RTL code, meaning they will wait longer to see the application while downloading code that will never be used.